# environment variables in babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, expo, babeljs

We need to modify certain configuration/variables in our React Native app (built using Expo) depending on environment (local/dev/staging/production). I've looked at a number of libraries meant for this purpose but all seem to have a flaw that breaks for our use case:

- [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (breaks because it tries to access 'fs' at runtime, when it's no longer available since it's not pure JS package and can't be bundled by Expo)
- [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) (can't use it with Expo because it needs native code as part of the plugin)
- [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) (kinda works but caches config internally and ignores any .env changes until the file importing the variable is modified)

As a cleaner alternative that does not require third party plugins, I'm considering using babel's [env](https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babelrc.html#env-environment-option) option and just listing all of the environments as separate json objects within `babel.config.js`. I'm not seeing much documentation or examples on this, however. Do I just add `env` field at the same level as `presets` and `plugins` that contains `production`, `development`, etc. fields as in example below:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: [...],
        env: {
            development: {
                CONFIG_VAR: 'foo'
            },
            production: {
                CONFIG_VAR: 'bar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would that work? And how would I access this `CONFIG_VAR` later in the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just ran into the same issues when trying to setup environment variables in my Expo project. I have used [babel-plugin-inline-dotenv](https://github.com/brysgo/babel-plugin-inline-dotenv#readme) for this.

1. Install the plugin

   ```
    npm install babel-plugin-inline-dotenv
   ```
2. Include the plugin and the path to the .env file in your `babel.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
      production: {
        plugins: [["inline-dotenv",{
          path: '.env.production'
        }]]
      },
      development: {
        plugins: [["inline-dotenv",{
          path: '.env.development'
        }]]
      }
    }
  };
};
```

3. In your .env.production or .env.development files add environment variables like this:

   ```
    API_KEY='<YOUR_API_KEY>'
   ```
4. Later in your code you can access the above variable like this:

   ```
    process.env.API_KEY
   ```

To access your env variables *within* the `babel.config.js` file, use the [`dotenv` package](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) like this:

```
   require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env.development' })
   console.log('API_KEY: ' + process.env.API_KEY)

   module.exports = function() {
   // ...
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked for me on my computer but doesn't work when I do "expo publish". Then the environment variable is empty...
Did you encounter the same problem?

Comment: nice! but do you know how to access the value of `API_KEY` in `babel.config.js` file itself?

Comment: @Zennichimaro you can use `dotenv` within the `babel.config.js` file like this: `require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env.development' })`. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @HarryTheo after following this, the API key is returning undefined in the console.